# Most efficient way to search for values from CPT in Post content

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

I have a Glossary CPT. Title, editor, slug and featured image.

I would like to add a filter to Post content (and content of my other CPT "species") which looks through all of the content in each post and replaces any words found in the Glossary with a link to the glossary entry.

For example...

*Glossary entry*: test

*Post content*: `<p>This is a test post to explain what I mean.</p>`

*Outcome after filter*: `<p>This is a <a href="/glossary/t/test/">test</a> post to explain what I mean.</p>`.

There may be up to 2000 glossary entries at any given time however, so I'm worried about efficiency.

---

**EDIT: THIS CODE NEEDS SOME REWORKING!**

I've started to use code [as suggested by Matthew Boynes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42008/6344).

I have adapted it somewhat, as I was receiving an error with my `$wordlist` variable.

More information on said error is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302605/).

```
function add_glossary_links($content) {
    global $wpdb, $wordlist;
    if ( !$wordlist && !$wordlist = get_option('wordlist') ) {
        mysql_query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000');
        $wordlist = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT post_title SEPARATOR "|") AS list FROM '.$wpdb->posts.' WHERE post_status="publish" AND post_type="glossary" AND post_parent>0');
        add_option('wordlist', $wordlist);
    }

    $wordlist = str_replace(array(" ", "'", ".", "/"), array("\s", "\'", "\.", "\/"), $wordlist);

    $content = preg_replace_callback(
        '/\b('.$wordlist.')\b/i',
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            'return "<a href=\"/glossary/" . strtolower(substr($matches[0],0,1) . "/" . $matches[0]) . "/\">" . $matches[0] . "</a>";'
        ),
        $content
    );

    return preg_replace('/(<[^<]+)<a\s.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/si','$1$2', $content);
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_glossary_links' );
```

The function above works, to an extent. I now have two issues:

1. The function is linking *everything*:

   `[<a href="/glossary///"></a>caption <a href="/glossary///"></a>id="<a href="/glossary///"></a>attachment_542" <a href="/glossary///"></a>align="<a href="/glossary///"></a>alignleft" <a href="/glossary///"></a>width="<a href="/glossary///"></a>125" <a href="/glossary///"></a>caption="<a href="/glossary///"></a>Amazonas <a href="/glossary///"></a>Magazine - <a href="/glossary///"></a>now <a href="/glossary///"></a>in <a href="/glossary///"></a>English!"]<<a href="/glossary///"></a>a <a href="/glossary///"></a>href="<a href="/glossary///"></a>http://<a href="/glossary///"></a>www.<a href="/glossary///"></a>seriouslyfish.<a href="/glossary///"></a>com/<a href="/glossary///"></a>dev/<a href="/glossary///"></a>wp-<a href="/glossary///"></a>content/<a href="/glossary///"></a>uploads/<a href="/glossary///"></a>2011/<a href="/glossary///"></a>12/<a href="/glossary///"></a>Amazonas-<a href="/glossary///"></a>English-<a href="/glossary///"></a>1.<a href="/glossary///"></a>jpg"><<a href="/glossary///"></a>img <a href="/glossary///"></a>class="<a href="/glossary///"></a>size-<a href="/glossary///"></a>thumbnail <a href="/glossary///"></a>wp-<a href="/glossary///"></a>image-<a href="/glossary///"></a>542" <a href="/glossary///"></a>title="<a href="/glossary///"></a>Amazonas <a href="/glossary///"></a>English" <a href="/glossary///"></a>src="<a href="/glossary///"></a>http://<a href="/glossary///"></a>www.<a href="/glossary///"></a>seriouslyfish.<a href="/glossary///"></a>com/<a href="/glossary///"></a>dev/<a href="/glossary///"></a>wp-<a href="/glossary///"></a>content/<a href="/glossary///"></a>uploads/<a href="/glossary///"></a>2011/<a href="/glossary///"></a>12/<a href="/glossary///"></a>Amazonas-<a href="/glossary///"></a>English-<a href="/glossary///"></a>1-<a href="/glossary///"></a>288x381.<a href="/glossary///"></a>jpg" <a href="/glossary///"></a>alt="<a href="/glossary///"></a>Amazonas <a href="/glossary///"></a>English" <a href="/glossary///"></a>width="<a href="/glossary///"></a>125" <a href="/glossary///"></a>height="<a href="/glossary///"></a>165" /></a<a href="/glossary///"></a>>[/caption<a href="/glossary///"></a>]
   <<a href="/glossary///"></a>p><a href="/glossary///"></a>Edited <a href="/glossary///"></a>by <a href="/glossary///"></a>Hans-<a href="/glossary///"></a>Georg <a href="/glossary///"></a>Evers, <a href="/glossary///"></a>the <a href="/glossary///"></a>magazine &#<a href="/glossary///"></a>8216;<a href="/glossary///"></a>Amazonas&#<a href="/glossary///"></a>8217; <a href="/glossary///"></a>has <a href="/glossary///"></a>been <a href="/glossary///"></a>widely-<a href="/glossary///"></a>regarded <a href="/glossary///"></a>as <a href="/glossary///"></a>among <a href="/glossary///"></a>the <a href="/glossary///"></a>finest <a href="/glossary///"></a>regular <a href="/glossary///"></a>publications <a href="/glossary///"></a>in <a href="/glossary///"></a>the <a href="/glossary///"></a>hobby <a href="/glossary///"></a>since <a href="/glossary///"></a>its <a href="/glossary///"></a>launch <a href="/glossary///"></a>in <a href="/glossary///"></a>2005, <a href="/glossary///"></a>an <a href="/glossary///"></a>impressive <a href="/glossary///"></a>achievment <a href="/glossary///"></a>considering <a href="/glossary///"></a>it&#<a href="/glossary///"></a>8217;<a href="/glossary///"></a>s <a href="/glossary///"></a>only <a href="/glossary///"></a>been <a href="/glossary///"></a>published <a href="/glossary///"></a>in <a href="/glossary///"></a>German <a href="/glossary///"></a>to <a href="/glossary///"></a>date. <a href="/glossary///"></a>The <a href="/glossary///"></a>long-<a href="/glossary///"></a>awaited <a href="/glossary///"></a>English <a href="/glossary///"></a>version <a href="/glossary///"></a>is <a href="/glossary///"></a>just <a href="/glossary///"></a>about <a href="/glossary///"></a>to <a href="/glossary///"></a>launch, <a href="/glossary///"></a>and <a href="/glossary///"></a>we <a href="/glossary///"></a>think <a href="/glossary///"></a>a <a href="/glossary///"></a>subscription <a href="/glossary///"></a>should <a href="/glossary///"></a>be <a href="/glossary///"></a>top <a href="/glossary///"></a>of <a href="/glossary///"></a>any <a href="/glossary///"></a>serious <a href="/glossary///"></a>fishkeeper&#<a href="/glossary///"></a>8217;<a href="/glossary///"></a>s <a href="/glossary///"></a>Xmas <a href="/glossary///"></a>list&#<a href="/glossary///"></a>8230;</p<a href="/glossary///"></a>>
   <<a href="/glossary///"></a>p><a href="/glossary///"></a>The <a href="/glossary///"></a>magazine <a href="/glossary///"></a>is <a href="/glossary///"></a>published <a href="/glossary///"></a>in <a href="/glossary///"></a>a <a href="/glossary///"></a>bi-<a href="/glossary///"></a>monthly <a href="/glossary///"></a>basis <a href="/glossary///"></a>and <a href="/glossary///"></a>the <a href="/glossary///"></a>English <a href="/glossary///"></a>version <a href="/glossary///"></a>launches <a href="/glossary///"></a>with <a href="/glossary///"></a>the <a href="/glossary///"></a>January/<a href="/glossary///"></a>February <a href="/glossary///"></a>2012 <a href="/glossary///"></a>issue <a href="/glossary///"></a>with <a href="/glossary///"></a>distributors <a href="/glossary///"></a>already <a href="/glossary///"></a>organised <a href="/glossary///"></a>in <a href="/glossary///"></a>the <a href="/glossary///"></a>United <a href="/glossary///"></a>States, <a href="/glossary///"></a>Canada, <a href="/glossary///"></a>the <a href="/glossary///"></a>United <a href="/glossary/k/kingdom/">Kingdom</a>, <a href="/glossary///"></a>South <a href="/glossary///"></a>Africa, <a href="/glossary///"></a>Australia, <a href="/glossary///"></a>and <a href="/glossary///"></a>New <a href="/glossary///"></a>Zealand. <a href="/glossary///"></a>There <a href="/glossary///"></a>are <a href="/glossary///"></a>also <a href="/glossary///"></a>mobile <a href="/glossary///"></a>apps <a href="/glossary///"></a>availablen <a href="/glossary///"></a>which <a href="/glossary///"></a>allow <a href="/glossary///"></a>digital <a href="/glossary///"></a>subscribers <a href="/glossary///"></a>to <a href="/glossary///"></a>read <a href="/glossary///"></a>on <a href="/glossary///"></a>portable <a href="/glossary///"></a>devices.</p<a href="/glossary///"></a>>
   <<a href="/glossary///"></a>p><a href="/glossary///"></a>It&#<a href="/glossary///"></a>8217;<a href="/glossary///"></a>s <a href="/glossary///"></a>fair <a href="/glossary///"></a>to <a href="/glossary///"></a>say <a href="/glossary///"></a>that <a href="/glossary///"></a>there <a href="/glossary///"></a>currently <a href="/glossary///"></a>exists <a href="/glossary///"></a>no <a href="/glossary///"></a>better <a href="/glossary///"></a>publication <a href="/glossary///"></a>for <a href="/glossary///"></a>dedicated <a href="/glossary///"></a>hobbyists <a href="/glossary///"></a>with <a href="/glossary///"></a>each <a href="/glossary///"></a>issue <a href="/glossary///"></a>featuring <a href="/glossary///"></a>cutting-<a href="/glossary///"></a>edge <a href="/glossary///"></a>articles <a href="/glossary///"></a>on <a href="/glossary///"></a>fishes, <a href="/glossary///"></a>invertebrates, <a href="/glossary/a/aquatic/">aquatic</a> <a href="/glossary///"></a>plants, <a href="/glossary///"></a>field <a href="/glossary///"></a>trips <a href="/glossary///"></a>to <a href="/glossary///"></a>tropical<a href="/glossary///"></a> destinations<a href="/glossary///"></a> plus<a href="/glossary///"></a> the<a href="/glossary///"></a> latest<a href="/glossary///"></a> in<a href="/glossary///"></a> husbandry<a href="/glossary///"></a> and<a href="/glossary///"></a> breeding<a href="/glossary///"></a> breakthroughs<a href="/glossary///"></a> by<a href="/glossary///"></a> expert<a href="/glossary///"></a> aquarists<a href="/glossary///"></a>, all<a href="/glossary///"></a> accompanied<a href="/glossary///"></a> by<a href="/glossary///"></a> excellent<a href="/glossary///"></a> photography<a href="/glossary///"></a> throughout<a href="/glossary///"></a>.</p<a href="/glossary///"></a>>
   <<a href="/glossary///"></a>p><a href="/glossary///"></a>U.<a href="/glossary///"></a>S. <a href="/glossary///"></a>residents <a href="/glossary///"></a>can <a href="/glossary///"></a>subscribe <a href="/glossary///"></a>to <a href="/glossary///"></a>the <a href="/glossary///"></a>printed <a href="/glossary///"></a>edition <a href="/glossary///"></a>for <a href="/glossary///"></a>just $<a href="/glossary///"></a>29 <a href="/glossary///"></a>USD <a href="/glossary///"></a>per <a href="/glossary///"></a>year, <a href="/glossary///"></a>which <a href="/glossary///"></a>also <a href="/glossary///"></a>includes <a href="/glossary///"></a>a <a href="/glossary///"></a>free <a href="/glossary///"></a>digital <a href="/glossary///"></a>subscription, <a href="/glossary///"></a>with <a href="/glossary///"></a>the <a href="/glossary///"></a>same <a href="/glossary///"></a>offer <a href="/glossary///"></a>available <a href="/glossary///"></a>to <a href="/glossary///"></a>Canadian <a href="/glossary///"></a>readers <a href="/glossary///"></a>for $<a href="/glossary///"></a>41 <a href="/glossary///"></a>USD <a href="/glossary///"></a>or <a href="/glossary///"></a>overseas <a href="/glossary///"></a>subscribers <a href="/glossary///"></a>for $<a href="/glossary///"></a>49 <a href="/glossary///"></a>USD. <a href="/glossary///"></a>Please <a href="/glossary///"></a>see <a href="/glossary///"></a>the <<a href="/glossary///"></a>a <a href="/glossary///"></a>href="<a href="/glossary///"></a>http://<a href="/glossary///"></a>www.<a href="/glossary///"></a>amazonasmagazine.<a href="/glossary///"></a>com/"><a href="/glossary///"></a>Amazonas <a href="/glossary///"></a>website</a<a href="/glossary///"></a>> for<a href="/glossary///"></a> further<a href="/glossary///"></a> information<a href="/glossary///"></a> and<a href="/glossary///"></a> a<a href="/glossary///"></a> sample<a href="/glossary///"></a> digital<a href="/glossary///"></a> issue<a href="/glossary///"></a>!</p<a href="/glossary///"></a>>
   <<a href="/glossary///"></a>p><a href="/glossary///"></a>Alternatively, <a href="/glossary///"></a>subscribe <a href="/glossary///"></a>directly <a href="/glossary///"></a>to <a href="/glossary///"></a>the <a href="/glossary///"></a>print <a href="/glossary///"></a>version <<a href="/glossary///"></a>a <a href="/glossary///"></a>href="<a href="/glossary///"></a>https://<a href="/glossary///"></a>www.<a href="/glossary///"></a>amazonascustomerservice.<a href="/glossary///"></a>com/<a href="/glossary///"></a>subscribe/<a href="/glossary///"></a>index2.<a href="/glossary///"></a>php"><a href="/glossary///"></a>here</a<a href="/glossary///"></a>> or<a href="/glossary///"></a> digital<a href="/glossary///"></a> version<a href="/glossary///"></a> <<a href="/glossary///"></a>a <a href="/glossary///"></a>href="<a href="/glossary///"></a>https://<a href="/glossary///"></a>www.<a href="/glossary///"></a>amazonascustomerservice.<a href="/glossary///"></a>com/<a href="/glossary///"></a>subscribe/<a href="/glossary///"></a>digital.<a href="/glossary///"></a>php"><a href="/glossary///"></a>here</a<a href="/glossary///"></a>>.</p<a href="/glossary///"></a>>`
2. This may be a pushing my luck, but would it be possible to make this code case-sensitive, i.e. content only matches wordlist if case is the same, unless it's the first word of a sentence?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: are you looking to make the changes on the fly, or are you looking to permanently change the content?

Comment: This certainly will have a very large footprint on your performance. How large is your typical content entry?

Comment: Hi gents, thanks for the responses. I would prefer to avoid changing the content mOr7if3r. Brian; our posts are typically-sized news posts as per majority of websites, say 200-300 words, but our species profiles can be very large. However, the latter is split into a number of meta fields (14, to be precise - genus, species, water chemistry, etc etc).

Comment: Its certainly doable. But will have a huge hit on your performance. So if you have 1000 glossary entries you will need to load all 1000 items titles and permalinks and then scan the post content for those titles then do your replace. The resource intensive bit here will be loading those 1000 glossary items on every hit to post_content. The solution would definitely need some caching system that updates when a glossary is updated/added/deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your input Brady. I'm wondering if simply loading the titles would do the trick - the titles will always just be a "sentence case" version of the text in the content, so I could do a `lowercase` then `preg_replace`. In addition, the slugs will always be the lowercase version of the title with hyphens replacing spaces and apostrophes being removed. I'm happy to do AJAX calls to the description etc. but obviously something needs to be loaded in the first place to determine whether or not the content is using glossary terms.

Comment: I have an idea of how you can do this efficiently. On average, which is going to have more words -- your glossary or the post content?

Comment: Always the post content Matthew, by a fair margin.

Comment: To mitigate the performance issues when makes the changes on the fly, you could just run a caching plugin. That way the modified content would be cached and the filter callback would only run when pre-loading the cache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a fun project. I think I could write an entire chapter in a book on this (in fact, I practically did below). Anyway, I messed around with a bunch of ways to do this, and here's the simplest way I came up with:

```
function add_glossary_links($content) {
    global $wpdb, $wordlist;
    if ( !$wordlist && !$wordlist = get_option('wordlist') ) {
        mysql_query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000');
        $wordlist = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT word SEPARATOR "|") AS `list` FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'glossary');
        add_option('wordlist', $wordlist);
    }
    $content = preg_replace_callback(
        '/\b('.$wordlist.')\b/i',
        create_function(
            '$matches',
            'return "<a href=\"/glossary/".strtolower(substr($matches[0],0,1)."/".$matches[0])."/\">".$matches[0]."</a>";'
        ),
        $content
    );
    return preg_replace('/(<[^<]+)<a\s.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/si','$1$2', $content);
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_glossary_links' );
```

#### Discussion

Assuming a table prefix_glossary of words, we're selecting a pipe-delimited list of all records. This will later become part of the regular expression when we search our post for the words. Before we do this, we're setting a session variable for group_concat_max_length, which by default truncates to 1024 characters. 100,000 characters gives you room for 10,000 9-letter words (and 1 10 letter word, to be precise), so you can up that if you need more.

In `preg_replace_callback`, we're replacing all instances of the words with themselves wrapped in anchor tags. Adjust the HREF as necessary.

This might have malformed some HTML (e.g. wrapping a word in an image alt with an anchor tag), so the next preg_replace fixes that. If you want, you could do another one to ensure that words already wrapped in anchor tags don't get wrapped in another anchor tag.

For performance testing, I built a glossary table of 1,001 random words 5-15 characters long. Performance does indeed suffer if the `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT...` results are not cached in some way, to the tune of a full second. As you can see, what I've done here is stored it in an option (of course, you'd want to update that option any time your glossary is updated). You could take any number of steps to boost performance here, and this is just one suggestion. Using apache benchmark to test, my page loads increased an average of 6.8% (with a very large standard deviation, so it's actually not a statistically significant difference, but I digress), which is on the fence; whether that is crucial or not is based entirely on how much traffic the site gets. Although, if it got a lot of traffic, one would hope it would have caching enabled anyway, in which a case the difference would be completely negligible.

#### Conclusion

This *works*, but you'd want to revisit the approach if that 6.8% was critical. Specifically, you could consider doing the replacements with javascript. You could do it in similar fashion, writing the wordlist out as a JS variable. This way your server doesn't have to handle the search processing and you let your users' machines do all the work.

#### Alternatives

Another way I tried doing this, which was significantly faster but required more coding, was to store an index when a post was published or updated. In that case, I searched the dictionary against every word in the post and stored the matches in an index table. Then on page load, replace the shortened wordlist in the post like above, so then I was only processing the list of known matches instead of the full list (so, say 5 words instead of 1000). If you wanted to explore that route, you need two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_glossary` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` tinytext,
  `definition` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1002 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `wp_posts_glossary` (
  `post_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `glossary_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And you'd create the index on post update using something like:

```
global $wpdb, $post;
$wpdb->query('DELETE FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts_glossary WHERE post_id='.$post->ID);
$sql_regex = rtrim(preg_replace('/[\W\s]*(\w+)[\W\s]*/','$1|',$post->post_content),'|');
$wpdb->query('INSERT INTO '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts_glossary (post_id,glossary_id)
    SELECT '.$post->ID.',ID FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'glossary WHERE word REGEXP("^'.$sql_regex.'$")';
```

I used my 1,001-word glossary and the 2,215-word first chapter of Moby Dick to test the indexing and it averaged ~1.5 seconds to build. Therefore, if you went this route, you should consider leveraging wp_cron so you don't have to wait for it to index after you hit "Update" or "Publish".

Fun stuff. Hope this helps!

Cheers~

Comment: I'm not sure I could join you in qualifying any of that as fun Matthew, but that's a fantastic answer :) From looking at your code briefly, and please enlighten me if I've read it wrong, I do have one issue: my Glossary entries aren't stored in their own database table, but as part of the "posts" table with a "glossary" `post_type`. In addition, I have a few posts labelled "A", "B", "C" etc. which I use as parents. Your second option of amending posts on submission sounds very efficient for our users, which is my primary concern. Could you give me a cron example? I've never broached the topic!

Comment: On using a CPT for this, no big deal, it just makes the query a tad more complex. `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT post_title SEPARATOR "|") AS list FROM '.$wpdb->posts.' WHERE post_status="publish" AND post_type="glossary" AND post_parent>0'`. On using the cron, it couldn't be easier. Hook onto 'publish_post', then use [wp_schedule_single_event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event). [Here's the gist](https://gist.github.com/1804885), so to speak. I winged it with this code and I didn't test it at all, so use with caution.

Comment: Fantastic Sir, thanks very much. I will be sure to try this over the next couple of days. If it works, as I'm sure it will, I'll award your bounty etc. immediately :)

Comment: Finally gotten round to having a go at this (blame t'others doing the Glossary entries, not me!). I've implemented your script, but the content is blank and I'm receiving the following error: `Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Unknown modifier 'c' in /my.wordpress.site/functions.php on line 380`. Any ideas?

Comment: In case this is a problem with the actual glossary list of terms, I've uploaded it here: http://pastebin.com/6XnWBJwM

Comment: If I change the line `'/\b('.$wordlist.')\b/i',` to `'/\b(test|amazonas)\b/i',` the error disappears. However, it breaks one of my links which says "Amazonas website" (changes the URL to that of the glossary) and also breaks the attached image (which has amazonas in it a few times) HTML.

Comment: I have updated my original code to show my progress. Please come back and help me Matthew! :)

Comment: Hey @dunc, I'm guessing that your glossary has a post name that's either empty or a . or something like that. I would try echoing the contents of $wordlist to see what it says, and make sure that your terms exist as something like "air-speed|velocity|unladen|swallow". To make it case-sensitive, you can remove the "i" from the end of the regex. If you can't get it working quite right, or need more (custom) logic, I'd recommend bringing in a freelancer. WP Answers can help with generic problems, but you won't get your app written for you :-). Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

The solution above are pretty good, and the performance concerns are right.
But the "caching" solution is really simple, so you can do it without much effort:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API
you should cache the list of glossary terms with a large timeframe (you can expect it being quite immutable: when you really need to update, use `delete_transient()`)

you can then modify the above script ( https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42008/12843 )
caching `$wordlist`

```
function add_glossary_links($content) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wordlist = get_transient('glossary_list');
    if ( !$wordlist && !$wordlist = get_option('wordlist') ) {
        mysql_query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000');
        $wordlist = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT word SEPARATOR "|") AS `list` FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'glossary');
        set_transient('wordlist', $wordlist, 60*60*24*2);
    }
    $content = preg_replace_callback( /*continues...*/
```

this will make mysql queries very rare.
However, if your wordlist is huge, the processing will still be a bit slow: to make it faster, use "standard" wordpress caching plugin, you won't look back!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Linkify Text](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/linkify-text/) plugin. It seems like it's doing a very similar thing, and you'd just have to modify it to use your glossary CPT for the terms instead of it's internal bank of terms.

You could run a caching plugin like WP Super Cache to avoid performance issues.

Comment: Hi Ian. Thanks for that - just downloaded it and had a look. The plugin seems to use a fairly basic `preg_replace` method which I suspect would be somewhat heavy for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean "heavy"? Resource-intensive, or overly complicated? I would guess that a regex would have better performance than some kind of manual loop.

Comment: Have a look at the comments on the OP Ian. It isn't that `preg_replace` is heavy in its own right; more the quantity of data that I need to search through in terms of the number of glossary entries and the amount of content in my Posts and custom post types. As such, I may well end up using `preg_replace`, but that doesn't address my issues of impact/efficiency. I will be running a caching plugin regardless, but I don't know a great deal about them. How much benefit will a caching plugin provide to a completely new user?

Comment: Yeah, I saw those, but I don't think the quantity will be an issue if you're using a caching plugin. Basically, the pages will be converted to static HTML *after* the regex runs, and those static HTML pages will be served to visitors. So, even if it took your script 45 seconds -- or, hell, even 5 minutes -- to run, it'd still be fine because the visitors would only ever get the static pages, which would be served almost instantaneously.

Comment: Doesn't WP already cache posts when you call them once?

Comment: It does have some caching -- for instance, if you call get_option() multiple times, the option will be read from the database the first time, and then from memory each additional time -- but as far as I know that doesn't extend beyond a single page load. It's cached for the current request, but not beyond that.